# Can group theory help solve this equation?

Tags: group-theory, linear-transformations

I am trying to solve the following equation:
$$
F(\mathbf{a}) = G(\mathbf{b})
$$
where $F,G: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The expressions for $F$ and $G$ are quite complicated, and I'm wondering if group theory would offer any advantage in solving this equation (i.e. finding the relationship between $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$).

For example if I am able to find all linear transformations $X \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$
F(X \mathbf{a}) = F(\mathbf{a})
$$
and similarly for $G$, would that offer any insight into the solution of this problem? By solution I would like to find some relationship between $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$.

Just wondering if group theory has ever been applied to this sort of problem, and if there are any books/references for this I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You may be able to prove that the set of all solutions has some sort of structure. Think of the way linear algebra gives insight to solve linear ODEs. But without details on $F$ and $G$ it is very difficult to tell.

Comment: Can you at least say what type of functions the complicated functions are?